# Service Bus existing farm join issue in windows 10 (home premium)

Tags: windows-10, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am facing issue while joining an existing farm using service bus configuration manager. This what happening at Configuration Process window:

```
Starting
Validating input and configuration parameters.
Installing auto-generated certificate.
Granting 'Log on as Service' privilege to the run as account.
Windows Fabric configuration started.
```

> Group WindowsFabricAdministrators not found.

I have service bus1.1 and the Windows 10 home premium. I have gone through lots of blogs to add the Fabric host service account to other groups but in home premium version of windows 10, I could not see the Users and Groups.

Anyone have any idea , kindly suggest what I am missing and could do to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried lusrmgr.msc in cmd?

Comment: And, by the way, probably tour version of Windows has restrictions on snap-ins. You could try [this](http://www.kapilarya.com/this-snap-in-may-not-be-used-with-this-edition-of-windows) solution.

Comment: Yes, I tried lusrmgr.msc, but it does not work with windows 10 home premium edition.. I will try with your other solution..